# How to convert mm-dd-yy to dd-mm-yyyy in php

Tags: php

IN PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5() I am reading date from first column but it throwing below format year as 2 digit but i want convert to 4 digit year with proper format

$date : 12-14-17

OUTPUT SHOULD BE

14-12-2017

Comment: Please do a search on either Google or here before asking a question. You will find most will have been answered already and all you need to do is give a good answer an upvote to say thanks

Comment: yes i got many answers for dd-mm-yyyy but not for dd-mm-yy here year has 2 digit

Comment: Read ALL the answers in the Duplicate Question and **extrapolate** to fit your requirement

Comment: You ca do something like this :-

$date = "12-14-17";
$d = explode("-",$date); 
$result = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($d[2]."-".$d[0]."-".$d[1]));

Comment: Anything you could ever want to do with dates is probably covered by [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) ...

Answer (score -2):

echo date("mm-dd-yyyy", $date)

Try this.It will help you.

Comment: yes i tried it displaying 01-01-1970

Comment: OP does not have a timestamp ???